# unique_ptr trouble? (VS 2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, unique-ptr

I’ve just copied some code from here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl, added `<memory>` and `main.cpp`, corrected `std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<impl>>`. Visual Studio **2015.**

```
// widget.h
#include <memory>

class widget
{
    // public members
private:
    struct impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pImpl;
};
```

.

```
// widget.cpp
#include "widget.h"

struct widget::impl {
    // implementation details
};
```

`widget.cpp` is compiled fine, but `main.cpp` is not.

```
#include "widget.h"

int main()
{
    widget w;
}
```

Error messages.

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1193): error C2027: use of undefined type 'widget::impl'
1>  e:\***\***\***\widget.h(8): note: see declaration of 'widget::impl'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1192): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::default_delete<_Ty>::operator ()(_Ty *) noexcept const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=widget::impl
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1397): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::default_delete<_Ty>::operator ()(_Ty *) noexcept const' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=widget::impl
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1227): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::default_delete<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=widget::impl
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1236): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Get_deleter_pointer_type<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=widget::impl
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1279): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Unique_ptr_base<_Ty,_Dx>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=widget::impl,
1>              _Dx=std::default_delete<widget::impl>
1>          ]
1>  e:\***\***\***\***.h(10): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<widget::impl,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=widget::impl
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1194): error C2338: can't delete an incomplete type
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1195): warning C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'widget::impl'; no destructor called
1>  e:\***\***\***\widget.h(8): note: see declaration of 'widget::impl'
```

Comment: The bottom of that cppreference page has a more complete example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `std::unique_ptr` has a deleter associated with it. When no deleter is specified it defaults to `std::default_delete`.

And what does it do? It calls `delete` on it, which requires destructor to be defined at that point. And that requires a definition there.

Comment: Added a destructor to `widget::impl`. Still nothing.

Comment: @J.Doe, you have to add it before the declaration of the `std:unique_ptr`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/g/AMDjLR).

Comment: But how exactly?

Comment: @J.Doe, define the struct and declare destructor inside header file. You can implement it outside.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but it doesn’t look right. I remember my past experience, I’m pretty sure I didn’t have to do such weird things.

Comment: @J.Doe, you need to get better understanding of what smart pointer is. Compiler has to generate a destructor for your struct, for which it needs to know if the smart pointer's member has destructor. It can't do some vodoo magic. So, as a general rule of thumb, think about unique ptr as an object, and object needs a definition of the type. Usual pointer wouldn't force you to do this. If you want you can declare your own destructor and implement it in cpp file, so you won't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Define the destructor of Widget empty in a separate cpp. Include the definition of impl in that cpp. The destructor of impl is called in that cpp because you included the definition.